# alternate VLC install location in Reaper

Tags: video, video-editing, audio-recording

Trying to edit some video in Reaper; VLC was installed before Reaper, but installed to an alternate location on the D drive for organization/speed purposes. Reaper, accordingly, doesn't know where it is, and gives a `VLC install path not found, install VLC 2.0.x-2.2.x` when clicking "Show Available Decoder Information". Is there a way to tell Reaper where VLC is actually installed, or would I have to reinstall at the default location? (I'd rather not) Thanks.